# Spring boot configuration properties validation not working

Tags: spring-boot

Trying to implement configuration properties validation for immutable beans as described in Spring boot docs:

- [@Validated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation)
- [@ConstructorBinding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle#boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding)

I'm using Spring boot 2.4.0.

Sample immutable properties class:

```
@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("prefix")
public class Props {
  private final String suffix;

  public Props(@NotBlank String suffix) {
     this.suffix = suffix;
  }

  public String getSuffix() {
     return suffix;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
     return "Props [suffix=" + suffix + "]";
  }
}
```

For a test, I did this:

```
System.setProperty("prefix.suffix", "value");
```

and I get the correct binding, i.e.:

```
Props [suffix=value]
```

However, by making a typo in the property name (added `1` to the property name):

```
System.setProperty("prefix.suffix1", "value");
```

I get this:

```
Props [suffix=null]
```

I see validation activated in the logs:

```
HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.6.Final
```

Form their [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-method-constraints), it is supposed to do constructor parameter validation:

> As of Bean Validation 1.1, constraints can not only be applied to JavaBeans and their properties, but also to the parameters and return values of the methods and constructors of any Java type.

Why is `@NotBlank` (full import: `import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;`) not causing validation exceptions?

Comment: Hibernate Validator looks for constraint annotations on the fields or getter methods for each property, that's why your validation doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero That doesn't seem to be the case based on their [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-method-constraints.html#section-declaring-method-constraints) - see the constructor annotation `public RentalStation(@NotNull String name)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that Spring is running the validations and it uses Spring AOP, which is a runtime implementation and by default and it constructors cannot be advised hence the validation won't work.
If you move the annotation to property or getter level it will work. I recreated your project locally and it just works when you move the annotation.